# hive regexp_extract

Tags: regex, hive

I use `regexp_extract()` to extract substring from string.

One type of substring looks like: `Abc-Def-ghi`
I use `regexp_extract(s, '^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}')`) to get it.

The other type of substring looks like: `wp.Abc-Def-ghi`

How can I get both types of strings using one `regexp_extract()`?

Comment: Tip: Instead of `{1,}` you can use `+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
regexp_extract(s, '^([a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\.)?(a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-?){3}')
```

Comment: The second alphanumeric group should be followed by a quantifier